# How to test async method in Vuejs's component when using jest and avoriaz

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, avoriaz

For instance, I have a component looks like this.

```
<template>
<div id="app">
  <button class="my-btn" @click="increment">{{ val }}</button>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      val: 1,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    increment() {
      fetch('httpstat.us/200').then((response) => {
        this.val++;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

*You can also check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ua7d1bzg/) as a simplified demo*

In order to do unit test for this component, I wrote code like this.

```
// Jest used here
test('should work', () => {
  // wrapper was generated by using avoriaz's mount API
  // `val` was 1 when mounted.
  expect(wrapper.data().val).toBe(1);
  // trigger click event for testing
  wrapper.find('.my-btn')[0].trigger('click');
  // `val` should be 2 when the button clicked.
  // But how can I force jest to wait until `val` was set?
  expect(wrapper.data().val).toBe(2);
});
```

It didn't work since `expect` ran before `fetch`'s done, but I've no idea how to let jest wait until promise function done.
So how can I test in this use case?

**Update** I tried nextTick but got no luck.

```
 PASS  src/Sample.spec.js
  Sample.vue
    ✓ should work (31ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.46s
Ran all test suites.
  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:477
    [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      2
    Received:
      1"

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:564
    { Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      2
    Received:
      1
        at /path/to/sample-project/src/Sample.spec.js:16:30
        at Array.<anonymous> (/path/to/sample-project/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:699:14)
        at nextTickHandler (/path/to/sample-project/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:646:16)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
      matcherResult: 
       { actual: 1,
         expected: 2,
         message: [Function],
         name: 'toBe',
         pass: false } }
```

Here's the complete test code.

```
import { mount } from 'avoriaz';
import Sample from './Sample.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';

/* eslint-disable */

describe('Sample.vue', () => {

  test('should work', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Sample);
    // console.log(wrapper.data().val);
    expect(wrapper.data().val).toBe(1);
    wrapper.find('.my-btn')[0].trigger('click');
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        // console.log(wrapper.data().val);
        expect(wrapper.vm.val).toBe(2);
        done();
    })
  });

})
```

**Update 2** I added `done`, but it still doesn't work. Here's the error message.

```
  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:477
    [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      2
    Received:
      1"

  console.error node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:564
    { Error: expect(received).toBe(expected)

    Expected value to be (using ===):
      2
    Received:
      1
        at /path/to/sample-project/src/Sample.spec.js:16:30
        at Array.<anonymous> (/path/to/sample-project/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:699:14)
        at nextTickHandler (/path/to/sample-project/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js:646:16)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
      matcherResult: 
       { actual: 1,
         expected: 2,
         message: [Function],
         name: 'toBe',
         pass: false } }

 FAIL  src/Sample.spec.js (7.262s)
  ● Sample.vue › should work

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

      at pTimeout (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:53:21)
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:523:19)
      at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
      at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)

  Sample.vue
    ✕ should work (5032ms)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.416s
Ran all test suites.
```

Answer (score 3):

Short story: get help from `flush-promises` (`npm i -D flush-promises`), and call `await flushPromises()` just before your `Vue.nextTick`.

Longer story, I have a `EmailVerification.vue` component with a `submit` method like this:

```
    submit () {
    this.successMessage = ''
    this.verifyError = null
    this.isVerifying = true

    this.verifyEmail({ 'key': this.key })
      .then(() => {
        this.isVerifying = false
        this.successMessage = 'Email verified, great! Thanks a lot. &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-home"></i><a href="/">Home</a>'
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.isVerifying = false
        this.verifyError = error
      })
  }
```

Here is my complete test passing:

```
const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(Vuex)

const $route = {
  path: '/verify-email/:key',
  params: { key: 'dummy_key' },
  query: { email: 'dummy@test.com' }
}

describe('EmailVerification.vue', () => {
  describe('Methods', () => {
    let localAuth = { namespaced: true }
    let store
    let wrapper

    beforeEach(() => {
      localAuth.actions = {
        verifyEmail: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce()
      }

      store = new Vuex.Store({
        namespaced: true,
        modules: { auth: localAuth },
        strict: true
      })

      wrapper = shallowMount(EmailVerification, {
        localVue,
        store,
        stubs: {
          RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
        },
        mocks: {
          $route
        }
      })
    })

    it('should trigger verifyEmail when button is clicked', async (done) => {
      const data = { key: 'another_dummy_key' }
      wrapper.setData(data)
      const button = wrapper.find('button')

      expect(wrapper.vm.isVerifying).toBeFalsy()
      expect(wrapper.vm.verifyError).toBeNull()
      expect(button.attributes().disabled).toBeUndefined()

      button.trigger('click')

      expect(localAuth.actions.verifyEmail).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(localAuth.actions.verifyEmail.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual(data)

      expect(button.attributes().disabled).toBeDefined()
      expect(wrapper.vm.isVerifying).toBeTruthy()
      expect(wrapper.vm.verifyError).toBeNull()

      const inputArray = wrapper.findAll('input')
      expect(inputArray.at(0).attributes().disabled).toBeDefined()
      expect(inputArray.at(1).attributes().disabled).toBeDefined()

      await flushPromises()

      wrapper.vm.$nextTick(() => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.isVerifying).toBeFalsy()
        expect(wrapper.vm.verifyError).toBeNull()
        done()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Then play with the return value of the `jest.fn()` mock function to return and test an error.

Note: I am using jest and mocha, not avoriaz.

Comment: The `nextTick` is not even necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`Vue.nextTick`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) and [`done`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html) inside the test:

```js
test('should work', (done) => {
  expect(wrapper.data().val).toBe(1);
  wrapper.find('.my-btn')[0].trigger('click');
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.val).toBe(3);
        done()
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi, Edd! Thank you very much for answering me. But I still got no luck with it. I updated my question, it seems that `val` remained to be 1...

Comment: I forgot to add done to the callback, I've edited my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: Hi Edd, I tried again but still got errors. Please check my new update.

Comment: The error looks like you aren't calling done in the next tick callback? I can't look into properly as I'm on vacation eight now, but the solution should be using done and nextTick